# Forcing div/image to bottom of screen regardless of the screen size

Tags: sticky-footer

EDIT 10.12am 17th April.`Your jsfiddle and on the emulator works perfectly and as I would expect however I am having no luck. My html is

```
<img src="/images/mobile/m_tech_fuss.png" alt="Payco Tech logo" width="100%">
<div id="wrap">
<div id="main">
<div><a href="page/127/Tech-Welcome.asp"><img src="images/mobile/m_tech_welcome.png"  width="100%" /></a>
</div>
<div><a href="page/125/Tech-Guide-to-Self-Employed-Contracts.asp"><img src="images/mobile/m_tech_self_e-contracts.png" width="100%" /></a>
</div>
<div><a href="page/126/Tech-The-Opt-Out-Notification-Explained.asp"><img src="images/mobile/m_tech_optout.png" width="100%" /></a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="footer"><a href="page/92/Self-Employment.asp"><img  src="images/mobile/m_tech_soundsgood.png" width="100%" /></a>
</div>
```

and css is exactly as you stated however not only does this not move the orange footer image at all but it also messes with my homepage layout :(

EDIT: 5.10pm 6th April

I found a guide which appears to work ok http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/keeping-footers-at-the-bottom-of-the-page

The orange footer stays at the bottom on any mobile screen however there is still some a gap between the last bit of content and the footer which forces me to scroll down whereas on a page where there is little content, the footer should just be sitting there already. Also this guide has messed up with my green strip images which are now no longer 100% in width :(

Here is my code:

```
<div id="container">
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="body">
<div><a href="page/127/Tech-Welcome.asp"><img src="images/mobile/m_tech_welcome.png" width="100%"></a></div>
<div><a href="page/125/Tech-Guide-to-Self-Employed-Contracts.asp"><img src="images/mobile/m_tech_self_e-contracts.png" width="100%"></a></div>
<div><a href="page/126/Tech-The-Opt-Out-Notification-Explained.asp"><img src="images/mobile/m_tech_optout.png" width="100%"></a></div>
</div>
<div id="footer"><a href="page/92/Self-Employment.asp"><img src="images/mobile/m_tech_soundsgood.png" width="100%"></a></div>
</div>
```

and my css

```
`}
html,
body {
margin:0;
padding:0;
height:100%;
}
#container {
min-height:100%;
position:relative;
}
#header {
background:#fff;
padding:10px;
}
#body {
padding:10px;
padding-bottom:70px;   /* Height of the footer */
}
#footer {
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
width:100%;
height:70px;   /* Height of the footer */
content:url("../images/mobile/m_tech_soundsgood.png");
}
#container {
height:100%;
}`
```

Comment: You may want to reorder your elements so that the image is after your page/content elements in the html. Other than that, use the answer below, or cut into a fixed-height element using a negative margin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want is for that image to always sit at the bottom of the screen, it looks like you are making it a bit too complicated. Try:

```
div#content
{
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
}
```

To get CSS sticky footer to work you can't have any content outside of the `#wrap` or the `#footer` divs or it will mess up the height calculations. It will push the `#wrap` div, which has a `min-height` of `100%`, down the page. This means that the bottom of the `#wrap` div is lower than the bottom of the screen. Resulting in unreliable behavior. Especially if the height of the content outside the `#wrap` or the `#footer` divs is of  variable height, which is what was happening in this particular case.

You can either place a header inside the `#wrap` div in a config much like this:

```
<div id="wrap">
  <div id="header">
    <!-- Header content -->
  </div>
  <div id="main">
    <!-- Main content -->
  </div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
  <!-- Footer content -->
</div>
```

Or you can leave it outside of the `#wrap` and `#footer` div and compensate by adding a `padding-top` value equal to the height of the header on the `#main` div. This is to stop the content inside the `#main` div from rendering over the top of the header outside of the  `#wrap` and `#footer` divs.

Comment: Ok sounds a bit easier but not there yet. I took your advice and used that code but used the class name 'content_foot' My html is now `<div id="content_foot"><a href="/enquiry.asp"><img src="images/mobile/m_tech_soundsgood.png" width="100%"></a></div>` and my css is `div#content_foot
{
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
}` I'm guessing somethings wrong with this though as it isn't at bottom of page.

Comment: That's interesting, here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZewzM/) with your and @AlexLynham's changes implemented, which does work. If it's not at the bottom, then where is it?

Comment: Should there be some images visible in your jsfiddle as I just see question marks

Comment: The image I want at the bottom is about a quarter of the way up, see screenshot here www.magnetikmedia.co.uk/current.jpg

Comment: Here's an updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ud6Dv/) which links in some images. For illustrative purposes I have linked in some images now and set the height of the fixed div to 40px. I see you're on some kind of smartphone emulator, have you set the viewport properly?

Comment: Ah, I updated the image links in your jsfiddle so I could see it and this is not what i meant. (still doesn;t work for me anyway bizarrely) I don't want the image static when scrolling. I just want the image to always sit at the bottom of the screen no matter on the amount of content available. See these 2 screenshots, this is how it looks now (as posted above) www.magnetikmedia.co.uk/current.jpg and this is how I want it to look http://www.magnetikmedia.co.uk/good.jpg

Comment: I have used the emulator here http://www.mobilephoneemulator.com but it is my own handset I'm testing on, a Galaxy note and an iphone 5. Results are the same as the emulator.

Comment: So using your globe example, I don't want to see the globe image until I scroll to the end of the content but for pages where there is not much content (ie. no scroll is needed like this one in question) then I want the bottom image to be locked and sitting across the bottom.

Comment: Ah I see, I can do that, in that case you were on the right track with the sticky footer approach. Here are 2 jsFiddles, the only difference is that the last 1 has less content on the page (to show you that it works) [jsFiddle1](http://jsfiddle.net/Ud6Dv/2/), [jsFiddle2](http://jsfiddle.net/Ud6Dv/3/). And you can get rid of the `div a img` CSS rule. That line is only for demonstration purposes. The height of the footer needs to be set for this to work.

Comment: Yeah this is it. Will try it out now.

Comment: Tried this, no luck yet! I have copied your code exactly (at least I think I have) I've updated the question with the current code I'm using

Comment: Ok, breakthrough. Not sure why but I changed something, reuploaded then changed back (so the code is as per my example above) and reuploaded and seems to be working now however if you look at this mock up I would expect it to look like this http://www.magnetikmedia.co.uk/right.jpg and not this http://www.magnetikmedia.co.uk/wrong.jpg To be clear, the image/footer is sticking to the bottom of the page but here it is classing the bottom of the page as being far down and I need to scroll to get there.

Comment: Ok I see if I change the padding-bottom and margin-top to 40px for example, it looks much better but still not right. It seems doing this makes it look great on an iphone but looking on a galaxy note, so larger screen, still doesn't sit across the bottom. I need it to be fluid ie. sit across the bottom no matter what size screen.

Comment: If you want the image that sticks to the bottom to be 200px high you have to make sure that `div#footer_mob {margin-top:-200px, height:200px}` and `div#main {padding-bottom: 200px}`. All those should be at + or -200px. And off course leave the other values in those classes alone. I'm just showing you an extract now to make the point clear.

Comment: And you might have to set a `padding-top` value on `div#main` to make the logo image reappear.

Comment: Ok, what value should go in margin-top as if I enter 50px as an example so it looks like this `div#main {
    overflow:auto;
 padding-bottom: 200px;
 padding-top: 50px;
}  /* must be same height as the footer */` it just makes the gap between the main logo and first 'welcome'image wider.

Comment: Basically, to fix this problem [http://www.magnetikmedia.co.uk/wrong.jpg](http://www.magnetikmedia.co.uk/wrong.jpg), you should add a `padding-top` on `div.main` of the height of the logo image, as the logo image should still be there, it's just not showing as it is behind the other images. So if 50px is too much, try 40px or 30px, decrease it until it is just right.

Comment: The logo image is still there though, this is why I'm confused. With the above code and including the padding-top: 50px; the only difference is that the orange strip is further down the screen off the page. See how it looks now http://www.magnetikmedia.co.uk/screen.png

Comment: There is some confusion with my 'wrong.jpg' screenshot, that isnt the top of the page, that is the bottom. By including the 'Why Self-Employment' and orange strip i though it would show how the orange strip has been pushed even further down.

Comment: In that case you don't need the `padding-top` at all, what is it like when you have things set up with the padding-bottom, height and margin-top as described in the earlier comment with the 200px as example value? Just change that 200 or -200 to positive and negative - whatever you need them to be (but make sure the numeric part is the same). It should work fine that way, if not please let me know how it is still not working that way?

Comment: I have played around with the pixel sizes but this doesn't really work as all I'm doing is trial and error to get the orange strip sitting right at the bottom of my phone. I have a Galaxy note so quite a large screen. It doesn't sit across the bottom on any other phone. It should sit across the bottom of the screen at all time, regardless of the screen size. My css code currently means it sits perfectly across the bottom of mine but this is no good to any other phone user, here is the code used for the dimensions. `padding-bottom: 70px; margin-top: -70px; height: 70px;`

Comment: Image on right is my large galaxy note screen where orange strip looks fine (as I messed with pixels until it was perfect) but then this is the same pahge on an iPhone, much smaller screen. You can see the difference http://www.magnetikmedia.co.uk/comparison.jpg If you look at the positioning of header and green images, they are relative to the screen size.

Comment: I now have it vice versa ie. looks right on iphone but as galaxy note is larger, it is still high up the screen there.

Comment: From what I can see here after testing this numerous times with different values, this code is simply setting the position of the orange image but as most screen sizes are different then if it looks correct one one it will still look incorrect on all the others.

Comment: @JohnFarrell Excuses for the delay, I'm probably in another time zone here. I have updated the answer with an explanation of your problem. I believe this will explain things properly. I've also made you an updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ud6Dv/16/) which I've then loaded into your [mobile phone emulator](http://www.mobilephoneemulator.com/?url=http://fiddle.jshell.net/ud6dv/16/show/&device=Apple-Iphone5) for demonstration purposes. You'll see it keeps working, even when changing to other mobile devices with different screen sizes and screen resolutions.

Comment: I've edited the question with more details. I appreciate all the help on this.

Comment: What do you mean with 'messes with my homepage layout', what else is on the page which you are trying to style? FYI, these 2 CSS rules: `* { margin: 0; }` and `img { display: block; }`, are only in the jsFiddle to get it to look right, they're not part of the css sticky footer approach, and they might break other things on the page. But I was under the impression that there were no other things on the page? If you want this to work there can't be anything else on the page.

Comment: The site is an .asp site with 2 include files, top.asp and bot.asp. These have to be referenced on each page. I had these references and your code and that was all. To be honest, the whole thing has got me baffled now as to not even being able to explain what I have! To give you an idea this is the page that you need to view on a mobile to see the mobile content www.paycoservices.co.uk/tech-more.asp I haven't implemented your code at the moment cos as soon as I do the homepage images are all over the place

Comment: If you could look at the page now and advise from there then that would be great. Otherwise I feel like giving up to be honest :(

Comment: I have actually found another solution whereby luckily it looks as if the image is stuck to the bottom of the screen anyway so what's the best thing to do, close this question?

Comment: Your call, I think the answer is true as it states that you can't have any content outside of the `#wrap` or the `#footer` divs if you want the CSS sticky footer approach to work. Next time maybe post the page source after it is rendered instead of what you are putting in on the server side, it would be a more complete picture.

Comment: Maybe add a link to the other solution which ended up working to the question? Or if it is the link to the guide which is there already, state that that is the guide that you ended up using. Just to create a complete picture for other people finding this answer later.